# What should I expect when switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, battery

I am wondering if anyone can advise on issues I might run into when converting a Windows 10 Pro ASUS Zenbook to Ubuntu. I am specifically wondering if the battery life will be affected at all, if there might be driver issues, and anything else that someone on here might have experienced. I've looked at past posts and it seems like many of them are old and might be outdated. The model is UX333-FA, specs:

- Intel Core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80 GHz, 1992 Mhz, 4 cores
- 16GB RAM
- 512GB Hard drive

I'm not sure what specs would be helpful and will spare you every single detail right now but I can definitely post them if someone requests.

I recently put kubuntu on my old 2014 MacBook Air. I've noticed with my converted MacBook that the battery life kubuntu shows is the actual capacity remaining (after 5 years of wear) which is about 80% at full charge (so the charger turns green when the screen says ~80%). The battery also does not last very long and I usually just have it plugged in anyway. I sometimes experience a little bit of a lag with programs opening, but the computer is old and only has 4GB RAM so that could be part of the problem.

Are these things I should worry about on a PC? And is there anything else I might need to know before installing? (I realize it's probably impossible to know, but just wanted to put it out there.) The ASUS is about 8 months old and I think I will just put regular Ubuntu on my Zenbook. Many thanks for any help you all can offer.

Comment: Great, thoughtful question. Start with [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu). You can try Ubuntu on your hardware WITHOUT installing it. Trying it out that way should answer most of your questions. Think about a plan to test Ubuntu on each subject you are concerned about. There's no hurry. Oh, and blog or post your results!

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. That is a very helpful starting place. I will try it out!